# Angular 2 Http – How to Get JSON Data from API with finance_charts_json_callback() callback

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-http

I'm trying to get json data from this api: http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/NFLX/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/json
And I don't know how to get into the returned finance_charts_json_callback().

I'm using Angular 2's http.get():

```
loadData() {
  return this.http
     .get(this.url)
     .map((res) => res.json())
     .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
}
```

When it gets to `=> res.json()`, it throws this error:

> EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i

Comment: if you log out the res object  without calling the .json method on it what is returned?

Comment: the response you are getting is not json, is something called jsonp, try to use use this instead: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Jsonp-class.html, an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675842/angular2-jsonp-call-with-promise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use JSONP in this case with callback name JSONP_CALLBACK:

```
loadData() {
    this.jsonp.get(this.url)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Where `url` should be `http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/NFLX/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/json/?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`, note `callback=JSONP_CALLBACK` part.

And of course, remember to bootstrap the app with `bootstrap(App, [JSONP_PROVIDERS])` and import `Jsonp` service from `angular2/http` module.

Comment: is not `JSONP_CALLBACK` in the url he's trying to get is `finance_charts_json_callback`

Comment: may i know what is `JSONP` i heared about JSON, `JSONP` term is new for me !

Comment: @Langley No, finance_charts_json_callback is a default wrapper callback used by API if you don't specify real one. For Angular machinery it is required response to be wrapped into JSONP_CALLBACK.

Comment: @PardeepJain Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) thread, nice explanations.