# Angular 2 Jsonp Err 200

Tags: angular

Using my jsonp call below, I get an error `Response with status: 200 Ok for URL`. If I understand correctly, this means that my get request actually worked. However, my method of calling the data didn't. You may find the link to my data either below, or by [clicking this link](http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myRun).

```
constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp){}
stockrun(){

this.jsonp.get('http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myRun')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((information) =>{
     console.log(information);
    });

}
```

The reason I entered `myRun` into the URL is because the data is organized differently when there is no callback, like in http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL.

I would also like to add that without `myRun` I get only the error 200 code. With it however, I also get `cannot find name myRun`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is not JSON. It's encapsulated inside `myRun(...)`, so to unserializing it, you should call something like

```
this.jsonp.get('http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myRun')
    .map(res => {
        // Get raw text instead of parsed object.
        let text = res.text();

        // Removing myRun().
        text = text.substring(6, text.length - 1);

        // Return manually parsed response.
        return JSON.parse(text);
    })
    .subscribe((information) =>{
        console.log(information);
    });
```

to remove `myRun(` and the last `)`.

You will have to call `res.text()` instead of `res.json()`, then `substring` the result and then call `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

Got the [answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233604/angular-2-http-how-to-get-json-data-from-api-with-finance-charts-json-callback). Basically,

```
var url = 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK';
this.jsonp.get(url)
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```